# Css and html 2 div's on one line then go next line

Tags: html, css, web

Hello im making a page where i need to have 2 divs on same line then automatic it will go to new line and make 2 divs there too and on and on.

[Image about how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0dwf.png)

I need two of the boxes on same line then it should start automatic on the next line and then with there is 2 boxes on line 2 it goes to line 3

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You need to post your code for us to help mate. Just an image can only tell us so much about the problem. Judging by the image you probably need a `display: inline-block;` setting.

Comment: give with for parent div 300px; and give 100px and use float:left for each child div.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CSS's `nth-child` pseudo-class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Firstly, set your `div` elements to `float` to get them alongside each other:

```css
div {
    float: left;
}
```

Now introduce an `nth-child` selector to make every other `div` clear the previous float:

```css
div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kc51q6g4/2/).

Comment: Never seen this nth-child before, seems quite useful! +1

Answer (score 0):

You could set all the divs to display:inline-block, then put a <br> tag whenever you want a new line.

Alternately, you could set all the divs to display:inline-block and put them in a container that has enough room for two divs across, but not enough room for three divs across. They should overflow to the next line automatically so you won't need to add break tags.